# Use COOKIES to redirect user with PHP

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I have a web page which consists of two parts: **english** and **armenian**. Each part is placed in one folder. Armenian part in `/arm` and english part in `/eng`. I need my `index.php` file in main directory to define if the user last been in **armenian** part or **english** and redirect him/her to that part. For that reason I have placed this code at the top of each php file in both parts:

```
$expire = time()+60*60*24*7;
setcookie("lang", $language, $expire);
```

and when user types `www.mysite.mydomain`, `index.php` file in my root directory must check the cookies and redirect the user to the `arm/index.php` or `eng/index.php`. Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
    header("Location: " . $_COOKIE['lang'] . "/index.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: eng/index.php");
}
```

The problem is that the user is being redirected only to `eng/index.php`. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Try var_dump($_COOKIE) in root index.php first to see what's set.

Answer (score 1):

`$_COOKIE` is not updated until the next request (when the browser sends back the cookie).

Simply set it on your own after setting the cookie:

```
$_COOKIE['lang'] = $language;lang", $language, $expire);
```

Comment: Now I`m doing
$expire=time()+60*60*24*7;
setcookie("lang", $lang, $expire);
$_COOKIE['lang']=$lang;
But that does not help at all. There is no $_COOKIE['lang'] set in index.php in main directory.